# Does PostgreSQL/PostGIS use R-Tree or R*-Tree?

Tags: postgresql, index, spatial, postgis, database-internals

PostgreSQL and PostGIS offer to create indexes over GiST with pretty much the same code. On 2D items, "This gives R-tree behavior" is what it says in the PostgreSQL [source](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/access/gist/gistproc.c) comments. However, it is a bit different than the original R-Tree, an observation being that the split technique is the Korotkov split. Furthermore, on [PostGIS source](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/svn-trunk/postgis/gserialized_gist_2d.c), there are comments suggesting R*-tree ideas. I am somewhat unsure...

So my question is: is the "R-Tree behaviour" offered in PostgreSQL the vanilla R-Tree? If not, what are some of the differences? Is this data loaded insert by insert or is there a bulk loading mechanism in place?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is the *vanilla R-Tree* but there is internal citations inside the source file you linked.  Also, the R-Tree inside of PostGIS is directly copied from PostgreSQL with these minor modifications (as in the FAQ),

> [**Why aren't PostgreSQL R-Tree indexes supported?**](https://postgis.net/docs/PostGIS_FAQ.html#idm1122)
>
> Early versions of PostGIS used the PostgreSQL R-Tree indexes. However,
>   PostgreSQL R-Trees have been completely discarded since version 0.6,
>   and spatial indexing is provided with an R-Tree-over-GiST scheme.
>
> Our tests have shown search speed for native R-Tree and GiST to be
>   comparable. Native PostgreSQL R-Trees have two limitations which make
>   them undesirable for use with GIS features (note that these
>   limitations are due to the current PostgreSQL native R-Tree
>   implementation, not the R-Tree concept in general):
>
> - R-Tree indexes in PostgreSQL cannot handle features which are larger than 8K in size. GiST indexes can, using the "lossy" trick of substituting the bounding box for the feature itself.
> - R-Tree indexes in PostgreSQL are not "null safe", so building an index on a geometry column which contains null geometries will fail. [GiST indexes are null-safe]

Comment: R-Tree and R*-Tree are two different things and R*-Tree has been shown to be superior (except for the fact that it is a bit more difficult to write). In-line comments inside of PostGIS have mention of R*-Tree whilst those of PostgreSQL don't; your FAQ does not address this. Sure  - PostgreSQL and PostGIS have similar implementations but they also have differences which your FAQ seems to not address...